# How Shopping Cart, Order Summary get quantity value?

Tags: orders, knockoutjs, shopping-cart

I found this page

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/ template/summary/item/details.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before_details') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<div class="product-item-details">

    <div class="product-item-inner">
        <div class="product-item-name-block">
            <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="html: $parent.name"></strong>
            <div class="details-qty">
                <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Qty' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after_details') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <!-- ko if: (JSON.parse($parent.options).length > 0)-->
    <div class="product options" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active'}}">
        <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'View Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <div data-role="content" class="content">
            <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
            <dl class="item-options">
                <!--ko foreach: JSON.parse($parent.options)-->
                <dt class="label" data-bind="text: label"></dt>
                    <!-- ko if: ($data.full_view)-->
                    <dd class="values" data-bind="html: full_view"></dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko ifnot: ($data.full_view)-->
                    <dd class="values" data-bind="html: value"></dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('item_message') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

How do I find where this "text: $parent.qty" getting value from?

[image]

Comment: What's your product type? Is it simple, configurable or bundle?

Comment: its bundle, want to get the bundle product correct qty

Answer (score 1):

The data you are looking for 'QTY' on Checkout page. That comes by **knockoutJS** in Magento 2. Knockout basically bind data to HTML template and serves dynamic content.

If you can check "**Application**" Tab (F12), In `Local Storage > Mage-Cache-Storage > Cart (Section Data)` driven from Knockout. You can see QTY, Options and all other parameters there.

If you want to check QTY data, please check below file.

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem.php
```

I hope that helps. Let me know if you have another questions regarding this.

Comment: Hello, if I want to find the value of qty? where should I look into? <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>. I did change the value, From the F12, it show qty:123 , however the frontend not showing the same, unless I get the wrong parameter.

Comment: How did you change the value? Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: I just hard code the return value. It did show at the value that I hard coded at cache-storage (F12), but the frontend still showing the old value. so I believe that "$parent.qty" is not referring the value at the Mage-Cache-Storage->cart->items-> qty...now I have no idea where I should trace where that qty come from.

Comment: What do you want with QTY?

Comment: I found out that my bundle products QTY not display correctly there, it always show 1 item, however, order and details summary is correct. I am also using ewave "Configurable Products In Bundles" extension as well, want to see where it goes wrong, it just like counting 1 bundle product, instead of their real qty

Comment: I just added a picture, wish you can help

Comment: Please check Quote module from where the QTY is being set.

Comment: is there anyway to echo out the $parent ?